# How do I find the coordinates of a vector if the basises are matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the bases

[image]

and

[image]

I need to find out if I can write

[image]

as a linear combination of the two basises.

If I had two m x 1 vectors I would just put them next to eachother. However what do I do if im in this situation?

I'm generally having a hard time setting up the matrices in my class cause I don't understand which values to put as rows and which to put as columns. I feel like i've seen cases where they sometimes put the vectors as the rows to solve for stuff, but mostly they put them as columns however I don't understand how to tell which one I should do.

Comment: If you were to "flatten" the matrices by writing it as one row (*or equivalently as one column if you were to flatten in the other direction*), having taken each of the rows of the original and laying them next to eachother, could you do it?  So, finding out if you could write $(1,2,3,3,2,-1)$ as a linear combination of $(1,0,1,1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,0,0,2,0)$?  There is no difference between solving this problem and solving your original problem.

Comment: As an aside, notice that every linear combination of $M_1$ and $M_3$ will have the resulting entries in the left-column be equal as well as the resulting entries in the right column be equal (*as it will be a linear combination of the left column of $M_1$ and the left column of $M_3$*).  Since $N$ has left column $\binom{1}{3}$ it is clear that $N$ is *not* a linear combination of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Just solve simultaneous equations as usual; go one entry at a time. Suppose $N=aM_1+bM_3$. The top left corner gives $a=1$. Moving one entry to the right, $b=2$. Now check whether $M_1+2M_3=N$. I fact it's not, viz. the top right corner.